# ¿Cómo hacer para que cuando seleccione un producto se muestren sus componentes?

Tags: php

Hay paquetes que tienen varios productos, y cuando selecciono un paquete quiero que se muestre los productos que lo conforman, hasta ahora lo que hace es que aunque selecciones un producto que no es un paquete muestra todos los productos que son de paquetes

Este es el query que tengo, el que muestra los productos de los paquetes

```
$sql2=mysqli_query($con, 
"select 
    admComponentesPaquete.CIDPRODUCTO, 
    admProductos.CIDPRODUCTO, 
    admProductos.CNOMBREPRODUCTO, 
    admProductos.CCODIGOPRODUCTO 
from 
    admProductos, 
    admComponentesPaquete, 
    tmp_cotizacion 
where 
    admProductos.CIDPRODUCTO=admComponentesPaquete.CIDPRODUCTO 
and 
    tmp_cotizacion.session_id='".$session_id."'");


+--------------------------+
| componentespaquete       |
+--------------------------+
| cidpaquete | cidproducto |
+------------+-------------+
| 578        | 42          |
+------------+-------------+
| 578        | 43          |
+------------+-------------+

+---------------------------------------+
| productos                             |
+---------------------------------------+
| cidproducto | codigoproducto | nombre |
+-------------+----------------+--------+
| 42          | 66kubar        | xxxx   |
+-------------+----------------+--------+
| 43          | 77kubar        | xxxx   |
+-------------+----------------+--------+
```

Lo que regresa el query son todos los productos que componen a los paquetes, no importa que producto seleccione se muestran todos los productos que conforman algún paquete. Lo que me gustaría que hiciera es que cuando seleccione un paquete, por ejemplo el 578 se muestren los productos 42 y 43.

Comment: para poderte ayudar necesitamos que nos muestres el modelo de de las tablas (solo los campos necesarios con algunos registros) lo que te devuelve la consulta, y el valor que esperas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que usas la tabla `componentespaquete` para poner en relación las tablas `paquetes` y `productos`.

Entonces, puedes hacer `JOIN` usando las columnas de esa tabla con sus llaves primarias respectivas en las tablas `productos` y `paquetes` y filtrar por el id de paquete.

Así, si por ejemplo quieres obtener los datos del paquete cuyo id es `1`:

```
SELECT pr.cidproducto,  pr.codigoproducto, pq.cidpaquete, pq.codigopaquete
    FROM componentespaquete_20171002 cp
    INNER JOIN productos_20171002 pr ON cp.cidproducto=pr.cidproducto
    INNER JOIN paquetes_20171002 pq  ON cp.cidpaquete = pq.cidpaquete
    WHERE pq.cidpaquete=1;
```

### Código:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/XIHYMF31416)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS productos_20171002 
(
    cidproducto INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    codigoproducto VARCHAR(10)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS paquetes_20171002 
(
    cidpaquete INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    codigopaquete VARCHAR(10)

)ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS componentespaquete_20171002 (
    cidpaquete INT, 
    cidproducto INT, 
    UNIQUE KEY (cidpaquete, cidproducto),
    FOREIGN KEY (cidpaquete) REFERENCES paquetes_20171002(cidpaquete)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (cidproducto) REFERENCES productos_20171002(cidproducto)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;


INSERT INTO productos_20171002 (codigoproducto)
    VALUES 
    ('66kubar'),
    ('77kubar'),
    ('88kubar'),
    ('99kubar')
;

INSERT INTO paquetes_20171002 (codigopaquete)
    VALUES 
    ('PAQ1'),
    ('PAQ2'),
    ('PAQ3'),
    ('PAQ4')
;

INSERT INTO componentespaquete_20171002 (cidpaquete,cidproducto)
    VALUES 
    (1,1),
    (1,3),
    (2,2),
    (2,4),
    (3,1),
    (4,2)
;


SELECT pr.cidproducto,  pr.codigoproducto, pq.cidpaquete, pq.codigopaquete
    FROM componentespaquete_20171002 cp
    INNER JOIN productos_20171002 pr ON cp.cidproducto=pr.cidproducto
    INNER JOIN paquetes_20171002 pq  ON cp.cidpaquete = pq.cidpaquete
    WHERE pq.cidpaquete=1;
```

---

### Resultado:

```
cidproducto        codigoproducto      cidpaquete      codigopaquete
1                  66kubar             1               PAQ1
3                  88kubar             1               PAQ1
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda! :)

Comment: ¿Resolviste el problema, @aline?

Comment: si claro, gracias por tu ayuda, me salvaste :)

Comment: Me alegro @aline. Para esta y futuras preguntas por favor lee: [¿Qué hacer cuando alguien contesta a mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Si la respuesta resuelve tu problema es bueno indicarlo para que no aparezca como sin solución.